# choosing user picked check boxes (dynamically created) in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I have a check box dynamically created as follows;(not the complete code here) there are a number of check boxes created, hence name is an array. (Is it right the way I have started the array inside `<td></td>`?)

```
while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";    
echo "<td class='tbldecor1'><input type='checkbox' name='delete[]' value='$Val1'></td>";
echo "</tr>";    
}
```

I need to get the user selected check box values to a loop in order to delete the records selected. If I forget about the deleting part of it, to get the user selected values to a loop I used something like below;

```
$AA = $_POST['delete'];
while($AA == 'checked')
{
echo $AA; // trying to print the user checked options so that I can subsequently code  to delete them.
}
```

but seems an erroneous approach! Can someone please give me an idea?

Comment: Why would it seem like an erroneous approach? Are you deleting large amounts of records?

Comment: @justderb I say this is an erroneous approach cos this does not echo and show me the check box values that a user has selected. Just nothing on the display when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's input field array which gives you all checked value into array in $_POST, so use following way

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  foreach($_POST['delete'] as $value){
    echo $value;
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: @GDB also if the $_POST['delete'] is not checked it leads to an 'undefined index' error! how do I avoid that? thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($_POST['delete'] AS $key => $val) {
   ...
}
```

checkboxes which aren't checked in the form aren't submitted, so automatically you'll only get the checked checkboxes in the _POST data.